# Copy to Clipboard Powershell Glitch

Tags: excel, powershell, dataset, scheduled-tasks

I've created and script with Powershell that copy the result of a dataTable into the clipboard in order to paste it in Excel:

```
        $excelArray = New-Object 'object[,]' $dt_table1.Rows.Count, $dt_table1.Columns.Count
        $excelArray = ForEach($Row in $dt1.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            $Record = New-Object PSObject
                            ForEach($Col in $dt1.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName)
                            {
                                Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName $Col -NotePropertyValue $Row.$Col
                            }
                            $Record
                        }
        $excelArray | ConvertTo-CSV -NoType -Del "`t" | Select -Skip 1 | Clip
        [void]$WorkSheet.columns.Item(1).cells.Item(2).PasteSpecial()
        $WorkSheet.Visible = $false
```

When i Exceute the script using "Powershell ISE" the script works fine, the problem came when i schedule this script using a CMD batch from the "Windows Task Scheduler". When the admin user is connected to the RDP and this batch is executed trough the scheduler it does not copy the result into the excel sheet, it copy the last thing i have in the clipboard.

When executing the batch and closing the RDP session, the batch fails without giving me an error..... What is happening? Maybe there is another way to copy the result of a datatable or dataset into an xcel sheet to avoid the clipboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way for working with Excel files is by using the module [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel). It uses the EPPLUS library so you don't have to use any COM-objects, install Excel on a server or use the clipboard.

One way of exporting data to an Excel file is simply using `Export-Excel`.

First you need to install the module from the PowerShell Gallery:

```
Install-Module ImportExcel
```

Then you can use it in your scripts:

```
# myScript.ps1
#Requires -Module ImportExcel

Param (
    $Path = 'C:\path\to\the.xlsx'
)

$exportToExcel = ForEach ($Row in $dt1.Tables[0].Rows) {
    $properties = @{}
    ForEach ($Col in $dt1.Tables[0].Columns.ColumnName) {
        $properties[$Col] = $Row.$Col 
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$properties
}

$params = @{
    Path          = $Path 
    WorksheetName = 'Data' 
    TableName     = 'Data'
    FreezeTopRow  = $true
    # HideSheet     = 'Data' 
}
$exportToExcel | Export-Excel @params
```

Some helpful commands to get you started:

```
Get-Help Export-Excel # displays what a function, its parameters, ..
Get-Help Export-Excel -Examples # displays how to use the function
Get-Command -Module ImportExcel # list all available functions in a module
```

Comment: Do you know where i can get documentation on how to use this module? I need to delete a range of rows because the data that i want to paste in the sheet should go into a table, before paste it i want to delete all the rows from the table without deleting the headers. I do this because i have a pivot table in another sheet that reads the table to show the data.

Comment: and... i have a lot of worksheets in the Excel file, this worksheets are the same as before, they have Excel tables used by pivot tables in another Excel sheets, so i need to fill all of those worksheets, update and save the Excel file updated in the main sheet to be send via mial to my clients.

Comment: The links to the documentation are in my answer. When you use `-ClearSheet` it will first remove all data in the sheet and then add the header row with the data rows underneath it again. You can use the correct name for the table in `-TableName` and your pivot table should still work. Thank you for marking this as solved or ask a new question if you need help for something else. You can also file an issue on the GitHub of ImportExcel.

Comment: Thanks! However, when i open my final Excel file generated the Pivot tables are asking me "There is data,do you want to refresh?" Should be refreshed automatically, i mark "Refresh automatically the pivot when the file is openned" but not working.

Comment: You should not rely on data already in the worksheet. Just create a new pivot table in that case on a new worksheet: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/tree/master/Examples/PivotTable

Comment: The problem is that the Excel file is a custom template, the Pivot table i have created is in a custom sheet called "Main", it already has the logo of my customer and so other colors and custom cells. This pivot reference the Excel table "Table1" in the sheet "1". Using COM Object i was able to refresh that pivot, now when open the file it always ask me if i want to refresh.

Comment: I just added the issue on the GitHub page. Hope this can be solved!